# Make a form that behaves like a message box in vb 2010

Tags: vb.net

My app is based on Visual Basic 2010/2012 (all its codes are same for both the languages). I want that I open a Registration Form above the parent form such that responding to the registration form becomes necessary for the user just like a message box. Can you suggest me a code. And please don't suggest very complex one. It irritates. :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `frmPopup.ShowDialog()`

Comment: -1 I googled you title. `Form that behaves like a message box in vb 2010`. The first 3 links explained in detail how to do it. Please consider rading the [FAQ] before posting again.

Comment: Read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open your registration form using [ShowDialog()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx)

```
Dim f As frmRegistration = new frmRegistration()
f.ShowDialog()
```

The ShowDialog method is used to display a **modal dialog box**. 
A modal dialog box blocks the execution of code following the call until the dialog box is closed.

Answer (score 0):

use `ShowDialog` rather than `Show`